# Python threading: iterating while removing elements

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, python-multithreading

I'm dealing with a threaded python program. One thread is iterating (by calling `iterate`) over a list. Another thread *might* (very seldom) try to remove an element from the same list using `remove_element`:

```
my_list = [ large number of elements ]
def iterate():
   for item in my_list:
       yield item

def remove_element(x):
   my_list.remove(x)
```

I don't want to use a lock for the iteration because the iteration might take a fairly long time, and I don't want to block the writer longer than absolutely necessary.

I'm worried that if the writer comes along at the wrong moment, I'll "lose" elements in the iterating thread: E.g. if the iterating thread is at element 1, and I remove element 0, then element 1 becomes the new element 0 and the iterating thread will "skip over" this element.

**Question 1**: Is this what actually happens, or is Python smarter than that?

Assuming I'm right about it, I'm looking for a solution. For various reasons, I *don't* want to copy the list before iteration starts (it's quite large and I need to conserve as much memory as I can). So I thought about the following solution:

When I'm iterating, I'm setting a flag that iteration is in progress. If the removal thread notices that, it doesn't immediately remove the element, but adds it to a `to_be_removed` list for later removal.

Once the iteration is done in the iterating thread, it checks whether there are elements in `to_be_removed` and removes them.

```
my_list = [ large number of elements ]
to_be_removed = []
iterating = False
lock = Threading.Lock()
def iterate():
   with lock:
      iterating = True
   try:
      for item in my_list:
          yield item
  finally:
      with lock:
         iterating = False
         while to_be_removed:
             my_list.remove(to_be_removed.pop())

def remove_element(x):
   with lock:
      if iterating:
          to_be_removed.append(x)
      else:
          my_list.remove(x)
```

**Question 2**: Is this a solid solution? Is there an easier solution that doesn't involve creating a copy of the list to iterate, and doesn't block the writer for the duration of the iteration? Is there maybe a standard library class that already provides what I need?

Comment: One scenario that i could think of which can lead to thread contention for the same resource - Iterating thread and remove thread both trying to remove the item from the list.

Comment: In answer to Question 1. No, Python isn't smarter than that because there is no way for it to tell what you mean to happen. Don't mutate lists you are iterating over. One common and safe way to avoid doing that is to iterate over a *copy* of the list: `for item in my_list[:]:`

Comment: I'm aware. But as I said, I don't want to iterate over a copy.

Comment: Perhaps not. But mutating the list breaks an assumption of the `for` statement, and if you do it the results are undefined. No matter what you do with locks. One safe way that I can think of is to use `for i in range(len(mylist)):` and deal with the shifting number of elements in `mylist` yourself, by having `remove_element()` provide a correction to `i`. But your alternative of postponing the delete *seems* sound.

Comment: Ah, right, I could manually iterate and fix the iteration counter if necessary. That actually sounds more efficient than what I'm doing, it would mean that I can do the write without any delay.